# Find index of object on a array

Tags: javascript

I want to search an array of objects to find the index of specific id. let have a look:

here is the array of my objects:

```
var sentences = [0,
{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "1-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "1-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
];
```

for example, I want to find the index of `id: "2-1"` which is `4`. How can I do that?

I have tried some like this without any success...

```
pos = sentences.map(function(e) { return e.sentences.id; }).indexOf('2-1');
console.log(pos)
```

Comment: do you have really zero at firts element following by objects?

Comment: :) yeah ... it makes my complicated code easer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way here is to use `findIndex()`

```js
var sentences = [0, { id: "1-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "1-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "1-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "2-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "2-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "2-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, ];
const res = sentences.findIndex(x => x.id === "2-1");
console.log(res)
```

The problem in your approach is that you are returning `e.sentences.id` from `map()` which will give error. You just need to return `e.id`

```
pos = sentences.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf('2-1');
```

By using arrow function

```
pos = sentences.map(e => e.id).indexOf('2-1');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take [`Array#findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) and check if the value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) to prevent `null`, which can not have properties.

```js
var sentences = [0, { id: "1-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "1-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "1-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "2-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "2-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }, { id: "2-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined }],
    index = sentences.findIndex(o => o &&  o.id === '2-1');

console.log(index);
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will help you find the object and index.

```
var sentences = [0,
{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "1-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "1-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
];

let res = sentences.find((each) => { return each.id == "2-1"});
let index = sentences.indexOf(res);
console.log(res, index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (hope that leading 0 is mistake):

```
var sentences = [{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "1-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "1-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-1", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-2", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
{ id: "2-3", layer: ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5"], difficulty: 4, track: "end", start: 4, end: 6, accuracy: undefined , accent: undefined, meaning_weight: undefined, shadow_weight: undefined, write_weight: undefined },
];

const elements = sentences.filter(obj => obj.id == "2-1")
console.log(elements.length != 0 ? elements[0] : null)
```